# Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted ( attempting draw image on canvas object )

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a cache of objects that can be used with canvas.drawImage() to display images but only draw them once. I keep getting this error, I have tried some answers found online like: `canvasObject.get(0) and canvasObject[0] and unwrap(canvasObject)` before putting them in the draw context, but none of that works. I cant find anything on it. hopefully someone can help. here is my code:

```
var canvas = full canvas that cached drawings should draw to
var temp = {};
var h = heightOfGridSquare; 
var w = widthOfGridSquare;

 var canvasElementForCache = document.createElement('canvas');
 canvasElementForCache.width = w * 2; // so that i can draw pictures larger then single grid square
 canvasElementForCache.height = h * 2;
 var cachedCanvas = canvasElementForCache.getContext(ctx);

// cache drawing in app object
var cacheDrawing = function ( name ){
    app.cache[name] = objectRepo[name](cachedCanvas);
};

var objectRepo = {
    someObjectName: function (canv) {
        var m = temp.coordinates;
        canv.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,200,0.9)";
        canv.fillRect(m.x + 25, m.y + 25,50, 50); // random filler (x and y are coordinates defined in the draw object funciton )
        return canv;
    },
};

var drawObejectAtCoordinates = function ( x, y ) {
     var px = ( x - ( w / 2 ));
     var py = ( y + ( h / 2 ));
     if ( app.cache[name] === undefined ){
            temp.coordinates = { x:px, y:py };
            cacheDrawing(name);
     }
     // drawing on actual canvas
     canvas.drawImage( app.cache[name], px, py );
};

var render = function () {
    drawObejectAtCoordinates( coordinateX, coordinateY );


  // this is just a place holder, my actual code is very long and has different rendering methods.. 
  // just know that it is being rendered ( not super important though since the error occurs at drawImage not render ) 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

this mostly exact, i have changed small parts for brevity.. but there is nothing left out that would be related to the issue im having. if anyone can help I would appreciate it greatly!

the error message is:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.
```

and when I console log the contents of the cached canvas object it looks like this:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D { canvas: <canvas>, globalAlpha: 1, globalCompositeOperation: "source-over", strokeStyle: "#41471d", fillStyle: "#ff8800", shadowOffsetX: 0, shadowOffsetY: 0, shadowBlur: 0, shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", mozCurrentTransform: Array[6] }
```

heres a jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/1krgqeq7/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues here that make this code rather difficult to follow:

1) You are reusing the variable `cachedDrawing` in a confusing way (is it an element or a function?)

2) You use a variable named `temp` which is usually a code smell, *especially* when you don't use it close to its declaration (not present in the code sample). Its also not clear *why* your stashing coords in there.

3) You use a fair number of descriptive variable names but in addition to temp you also use the rather non-descript 'obj'

But the answer to your question (related to 1 above) is that you are passing a *context*, not the canvas it was gotten from. Don't reassign that var and pass it into the cache instead.

Problems like this will likely be easier to spot with more descriptive variable names like `cachedCanvas` being a canvas and `cachedCtx` being its context.

Comment: the cachedDrawiing is is the canvas ( var cachedDrawing = document.createElement('canvas'); ).. I can see now how that could be confused with the function ( cacheDrawing ) emphesis on cache, not cached.. which caches the drawing... the temp thing is a long story, but regardless.. thank you for your answer! would you mind elaborating on what you mean by im passing a context? how do i cache the drawing and not the context? obj is a repository for objects/drawings.. there are many different objects to chose from when deciding which to draw, you specify them by name.

Comment: The relevant lines in your code are `var cachedCanvas = canvasElementForCache.getContext(ctx);` which assigns the results of the `.getContext()` method to the var and `app.cache[name] = objectRepo[name](cachedCanvas);` which caches it of course. But that object you're passing to your function is a *context* (result of the `.getContext()` method) not the canvas element whose method you invoke. It cannot be supplied as an argument to `drawImage()`, you need to use the actual canvas element.

Comment: so pass `objectRepo[name](canvasElementForCache);` instead of `objectRepo[name](cachedCanvas);` ? I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding, because the way ive used canvas before uses the result of get context and has no problems. so what i dont understand is how the variable resulting from `getContext()` is not the canvas element.. and then seeing as it is not the canvas element, what do i need to cache if not the result of `canvasElement.getContext()`. I hope I am explaining what I am misunderstanding. I thank you for your patience, I haven't been using canvas very long

Comment: Correct (on what you need to pass to the caching function). I know its a bit confusing at first: the layer of indirection is there for good reasons but it doesn't make life easier for beginners. Another way to think of it is the context is the interface, the canvas is the instance (if that makes sense).